# Wrong image path after migration from 1.9.4 to 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, migration, data-migration-tool

I have an issue about the image URL after a migration from Magento 1.9.4 to 2.3.
I have some products images which are displayed and some which are not.
Then I found out the reason which is due to some letter that should be an uppercase or lowercase.

Example:

```
Image not displayed
pub/media/catalog/product/cache/2765542505660baab28ecd555e27366e/v/r/vrac_5.jpg

Image displayed
pub/media/catalog/product/cache/2765542505660baab28ecd555e27366e/V/r/vrac_5.jpg
```

Does had this issue before? And have a solution to fix this ?

Comment: Did you tried sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize to regenerate resized product images

Comment: @PritamInfo24

I did it but I got an error out "File '/pub/media/catalog/product/i/m/image3861_2.jpg' does not exist." 

I don't know what to do ...

Comment: It means the image file not exist (/pub/media/catalog/product/i/m/image3861_2.jpg) but in db the path is saved. you may try to use sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize -f to generate product image ommiting error.

Comment: @PritamInfo24 
-f parameter doesn't exist  
`sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize -f`

When I use the command catalog:images:resize, I have now this output:
`Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in .../vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php on line 305`

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: You are showing a cached folder, can you remove all cache and rebuild?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I already tried it by removing manually the all folders in /cache and still not working. I also tried to rename all folders and files in lowercase and the changed in database all the value in 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' table and set it to lowercase but still not working. I'm out of idea....

Comment: Finally, made it work, I had to update the value of the column small_image and thumbnail in lowercase from catalog_product_flat_1 as well.

I don't know if It's a clean way to do it but it works :)